# jQuery Mobile with Ajax call to remote server not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I am trying the following code to call .asmx webserivce, however, its returning [object Object]

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>   </title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.3/jquery.mobile-1.4.3.min.css" />
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.3/jquery.mobile-1.4.3.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="icon.css" type="text/css">
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="js/wormhole.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
document.addEventListener(
        "backbutton",
        function()
        {
            mosync.app.exit();
        },
        true);

        $(document).bind("mobileinit",function(){
            $.mobile.page.prototype.options.addBackBtn = true;  
    $.mobile.allowCrossDomainPages=true;
    $.support.cors= true;
  });

  $(document).ready(function(e) {
    $.ajax({
    url: 'http://webservice.gkg4.com/Test.asmx/HelloWorld',
    type: 'POST',
    crossDomain: true,
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",

    dataType: 'json',
    success: function(result){
        alert(result);
    },
    error: function(result){
        alert(result);
    }
});
});
    </script>

</head>

<body>
<div data-role="page" id="home">
  <div data-role="header">
    <img src="image/png/chat.png" alt="image">
    <a href="#popupPanel" data-rel="popup" data-role="button" class="ui-btn  ui-icon-grid ui-btn-icon-left ui-btn-right ui-btn-icon-notext">Menu</a>

<div data-role="popup" id="popupPanel" >
<ul data-role="listview" data-inset="true" style="min-width:210px;" data-theme="b">
                    <li data-role="divider" data-theme="a">Menu</li>
                    <li><a href="aboutus.html">About Us</a></li>
                    <li><a href="contactus.html">Contact Us</a></li>
            <li><a href="#" id="chat" rel="external" >Live Chat</a></li>
            <li><a href="#" onclick="mosync.app.exit();">Exit</a></li>
                </ul>    
</div>
  </div>
  <div data-role="content" data-theme="b">
  <div style="text-align:center">

  </div>
  <h4><center> Member's Login</center></h4>
  </div>

  <div data-role="footer" data-position="fixed">
<div data-role="navbar" data-iconpos="left">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

The URL for webservice is live so you can check the same at your end.
Any help appreciated.
Code in in document.Ready section

Answer (score 0):

Is the page where you are calling from also from webservice.gkg4.com? If not, it is illegal to call ajax from a different domain, and the alert that you are seeing is actually from the error handler.

Another problem is that the contentType is json, whereas the web service is returning XML.

Comment: That's the thing, I need cross Domain call. I already wrote the crossDomain: true; Also, in the webservice, I added     **[ScriptMethod(ResponseFormat = ResponseFormat.Json)]** so I believe its JSON and not XML.

Comment: I am testing the current page offline from my computer and also, trying the same from MOSync, by creating APK and installing it to Android mobile.

Comment: Type in http://webservice.gkg4.com/Test.asmx/HelloWorld in your address bar - you can see clearly it is XML. Perhaps post a separate question for why ResponseFormat is not working.

Comment: Alright, let's assume its XML, and I change the jquery from JSON to XML. Even then its not working. So its not the issue of returning DateType, its simply not calling the webservice.

Comment: As for the cross domain problem - you will need to use jsonp - look at http://learn.jquery.com/ajax/working-with-jsonp/.

Comment: I tried everything and unable to get it working. I am using .net FW 4.0, any help appreciated.